# Postgres ignoring composite GIN Index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I'm having problems with Postgres ignoring a composite GIN index when I run this query:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM "data_killmail"
 WHERE "data_killmail"."tags" @> (ARRAY['70:1812482933'])::varchar(32)[]
 ORDER BY "data_killmail"."killmail_time" DESC
 limit 50;
```

There are GIN indexes for both `killmail_time`/`tags` and `tags`/`killmail_time`, yet as shown in this explain it's using a btree index on `killmail_time` to apply the sort/limit and doing an index scan for `tags`.

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..3918.64 rows=50 width=680) (actual time=1.946..6686.040 rows=6 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan Backward using data_killmail_killmail_time_538e642b on data_killmail  (cost=0.43..353971.77 rows=4517 width=680) (actual time=1.945..6686.038 rows=6 loops=1)
        Filter: (tags @> '{70:1812482933}'::character varying(32)[])
        Rows Removed by Filter: 2134864
Planning Time: 1.294 ms
Execution Time: 6686.147 ms
```

The table has over 2 million rows so I don't imagine its a small dataset issue.

If I simply delete the `killmail_time` btree index and run the same query again then it uses the composite GIN index as intended with dramatically better performance.

```
Limit  (cost=16629.09..16629.21 rows=50 width=680) (actual time=0.869..0.871 rows=6 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=16629.09..16640.45 rows=4546 width=680) (actual time=0.868..0.869 rows=6 loops=1)
        Sort Key: killmail_time DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 32kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on data_killmail  (cost=443.23..16478.07 rows=4546 width=680) (actual time=0.796..0.804 rows=6 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (tags @> '{70:1812482933}'::character varying(32)[])
              Heap Blocks: exact=3
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on data_killma_killmai_4b3756_gin  (cost=0.00..442.10 rows=4546 width=0) (actual time=0.787..0.788 rows=6 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (tags @> '{70:1812482933}'::character varying(32)[])
Planning Time: 1.087 ms
Execution Time: 1.276 ms
```

If I remove either the `LIMIT` or `ORDER BY` it executes similarly using the GIN index with the same 1-4ms execution time.

If I wrap the table and use `OFFSET 0` to force the execution order as shown below then again, 1-4ms execution time.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
      FROM "data_killmail"
     WHERE "data_killmail"."tags" @> (ARRAY['70:1812482933'])::varchar(32)[]
     OFFSET 0 ) dk
ORDER BY "dk"."killmail_time" desc
LIMIT 10
```

I can probably make this query work fine in my application using this workaround but I'm more concerned with what's going on here as this is far from the only query that would benefit from this index.

I've also tried changing the settings described in this answer to no avail.

Any thoughts?

edit: that answer clearly doesn't address my question. "Just order by a different column or delete the index" is obviously not a real solution and I explicitly pre-emoted that.